# Split screen application iPad

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

> I want to create an iPad application in which there are four windows on single screen.
>   these windows should be updating simultaneously (Multitasking). How i can do this any suggestion/help will be appreciable

Comment: This question is very broad.

Comment: @rmaddy: at least few clue how to start ?

Comment: Your question is far too vague to offer any suggestions. You need to ask much more specific questions.

Comment: 1) For 4 windows, use 4 UIViews or subclasses of UIVIews. 2). For updating the view, you have to do it in main thread. I am not sure if UI Operations can be done in background thread. Any other operations can be done using NSOperationQueue or so.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume that you mean views and not windows.

First, make sure you're not over-complicating the interface. It should be intuitive, and four distinct simultaneous views sound like a lot (of course, it depends).

Second, create a UIViewController. Then, create four UIView subclasses, with all the properties and objects you need, lay them out as subviews, and build the logic into the UIViewController, which can be the delegate for them.

I hope this helps get you started in the right direction, but as others have said, this is a broad question and there are many applicable approaches.